# C# money exchange algorithm

Tags: c#

I need to determine the given input into all possible banknote combinations.

```
int[] currency = new int[] { 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500 };
int total = 20; // result is { {5,5,5,5} {5,5,10} {10,10} {20} }

int[][] result = GetCombinations(total, 0, currency); // should return the 4 combinations
```

Here is what I've tried so far.

```
public static int GetCombinations(int total, int index, int[] list)
{   
    total = total - list[index];
    if (total < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (total == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1 + GetCombinations(total, index + 1, list);
    }
}
```

**QUESTION for Bounty:**

I need a way to get all combinations - not just the count.

Comment: This is an question comming up today several times: Please Google "the coin changing Problem" since it is a common algorithm question: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/

Comment: You get 2 because if you were to write it down you'd see the inputs to the recursions are `15, 1` then `5, 2` which means 5 - 20 is less than 0. None of this code is designed to return the combinations though

Comment: There should be a loop in this recursive function so that calling `GetCombination` inside the loop should cover all possible cases, including cases where the next note is the same as the current one. Also, call to `GetCombinations` should change the `total` parameter as well.

Comment: this is a dynamic programming problem!
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/coin-change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only calculating {5}, {5, 10}. 
You are calculating "How many different coins can use if the cost <= 20?". 
So, you have to count for this algorithm. 
The correct code is:

```
public static int GetCombinations(int total, int index, int[] list)
{  
    if (total == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(index == list.Length) {
        return 0;
    }
    int ret = 0;
    for(; total >= 0; total -= list[index])
    {
        ret += GetCombinations(total, index + 1, list);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If you want to calculate the number of combinations, you can also solve dynamic programming and memorize for `dp[total][index]`, because `GetCombinations(total, index, list)` value is same if total and index is same.


EDIT: 
If you want ALL combinations, you can do like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Program {
    public static int GetCombinations(int total, int index, int[] list, List<int> cur) {  
        if (total == 0) {
            foreach(var i in cur) {
                Console.Write(i + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            return 1;
        }
        if(index == list.Length) {
            return 0;
        }
        int ret = 0;
        for(; total >= 0; total -= list[index]) {
            ret += GetCombinations(total, index + 1, list, cur);
            cur.Add(list[index]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < cur.Count; i++) {
            while(cur.Count > i && cur[i] == list[index]) {
                cur.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
    public static void Main() {
        int[] l = { 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500 };
        GetCombinations(20, 0, l, new List<int>());
    }
}
```

I improved my code and now you're able to enumerate ALL combinations using recursion.
In this code, it enumerates combinations in lexicographical order.
I verified for `sum=20, 75` cases.

Comment: side question - can this method also be used to output all combinations?

Comment: No, only number of ways. If you want to output all combinations, use backtracking.

Comment: I improved my code and it also count all combinations.

Comment: I've edited this code and I deleted static List<int> cur.